# SQL Server Data Base Application Role - Can we configure application to Windows Service , WCF / Web API service

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can we configure SQL application role for external Applications like - Windows Service , WCF / Web API service.

Regards
Abdul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a SQL Application Role for any application type you like, as long as the code you're writing for the application is able to use roles. It's not a SQL limitation. Most languages (e.g. c#) allow roles to be used.

Comment: Thanks Greg, You meant we have to use the command - sp_setapprole in every DB connection from C#

Comment: Yep, set it for each role

Comment: Thanks Greg and appreciated your response